# Anyone has Avast reporting false positive on web protection?

Tags: web, antivirus, false-positive

I have a website built on HTML5 initializr.com bootstrap code.
Until last week it worked fine. Today my AVAST antivirus installed on windows started blocking the navigation on this website because of Infection: JS:Decode-AQE [Trj] (Trojan Horse it says...)

Well the files on the server haven't been modified since a month. That was my first check, if ever someone tried to hack the site.

So nothing changed on files. Furthermore on other system without AVAST the website runs fine.
Actually I saw before hacked websites,,, and in such a case it's google itself blocking a website because contains malaware. (This website is correctly indexed by google no malaware detected)

The only solutions I found until now is to whitelist on AVAST the Domain name, but I wish there could be something better.

Also... since this website is made upon very standard code... I imagine more people will have this problem with clients running Avast AV.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 4):

I've found that there are more cases of false positives with Avast on web protection.
If ever happen to you just check first if your website is really clean with a online tool such as:

http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

(Anyway Google is usually the first entity reporting you about malaware:

look in: Webmasters tools->Health->Malaware)

and then report the false positive to Avast at:

http://www.avast.com/contact-form.php